# Sum of this infinite series...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

> Find the sum of the infinite series:
>   $$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6\cdot 12}+\frac{5\cdot 8}{6 \cdot 12 \cdot 18}+\frac{5 \cdot 8 \cdot 11}{6 \cdot 12 \cdot 18 \cdot 24}+\dots$$

I am not able to relate this series to any of the famous power series . I am not getting any clues how to start . I wrote the general term but that didn't help too.

Comment: Have you already tried to write down the sequence?

Comment: No I haven't. , But what is the benefit of that?

Comment: You can see ways to simplify the "unknown" sequence into a known one., for example notice that $6\cdot12\cdot18\cdots(6n) = 6^n\cdot (n!)$

Comment: It's necessary in order to get the limit.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The $n$-th term is $$\frac{1}{2}\,\binom{-2/3}{n+1}\,\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\,,$$
where $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.  After some simplification, you should obtain $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}-\dfrac12$ as the final answer.